# Eclipse: Is it Possbile to Set Breakpoint on a Whole Module

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have the following 2 questions regarding Eclipse debugger:

1. The application that I work on consists of a large number of Maven modules.  Is it possible to set a break point on a whole module?
2. I often have to work on applications that I have no prior knowledge of, and thus don't know where to put a breakpoint. Is there a good place to set a break point in such apps to stop the debugger? Then I can just use the step debugger to trace and see what the code is doing.

Thanks

Comment: I think that 1) no 2) you need to learn a bit about the app code you are working with to determine where to put an initial breakpoint.  For example, to see what part of the code handles a button click, start with the name of the button (or page/screen) and search your code for it.  Having a breakpoint at a high level will help you set a start point and drill-down from there (giving you a chance to get to know the code better in the process) - Also, different strategies apply for web vs desktop vs mobile apps but the gist of searching for an UI element (i.e. by name) will work almost always

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a good strategy.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, breakpoints are a *point*, namely a line, in the code where you would like execution to stop.  The JVM has no notion of separate Maven modules, so cannot break on that basis.
2. What information do you start with? Presumably you're not literally looking at a .zip of code you know nothing about.  You can place a breakpoint in the `main()` method to break (almost) as soon as the application starts, or identify other core classes and place breakpoints in them.  Other than the actual application entry point (`main()` and so on), there is no standard "good" place to put a breakpoint in order to see what the code is doing.